# RemoveLinkByName doesn't work to remove links in customer dashboard - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, local.xml, dashboard

I want to remove some links in customer dashboard but the removeLinkByName doesn't work for me, Where i can find the name of these links ?  here is my code:

**local.xml:**

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
          <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"></remove>
          <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>downloadable_products</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

**The error:**

```
Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation::removeLinkByName(Array
(
    [0] => downloadable_products
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to rewrite this block and add the removeLinkByName() function

```
public function removeLinkByName($name)
    {
        unset($this->_links[$name]);
        return $this;
    }
```